# kiosk app full screen

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-app

I have built a kiosk app for Chrome with app builder, but even if the key of doing a kiosk app is that it will be displayed at full screen, I don´t manage to get rid of the top bar (I have removed the homepage button etc. but can´t display it at total full screen). I`d like to know if there´s any commando for this in html or javascript and in which file it should be added.

In the backgroung.js file I´ve added the line "state: 'fullscreen' but it does not work (I've also added the permission for fullscreen in the manifest file):

```
    var runApp = function() {
  if (chrome.power) {
    chrome.power.requestKeepAwake('display');
  }
  console.log(config);
  chrome.app.window.create(
      config ?
      'exported_app_view.html' :
      'designer_view.html',
      {
        id: 'KioskDesignerWindow',
        width: 1100,
        height: 720,
        minWidth: 800,
        minHeight: 600,
        state: 'fullscreen' 
      },
      function(win) {
        if (!this.X) { return; }
        var window = win.contentWindow;
        window.onload = function() {
          this.$addWindow(window);
          var Y = this.X.subWindow(window, 'Kiosk Designer Window');
          this.DOM.init(Y);
        }.bind(this);
        win.onClosed.addListener(function() {
          this.$removeWindow(window);
        }.bind(this));
      }.bind(this));
}.bind(this);
```

Comment: See [detect the the title bar height for a window for different operating systems with javascript](//stackoverflow.com/a/33741035)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it with JavaScript.  In background.js, your 3rd parameter to chrome.app.window.create is that callback function that has the `win` argument - add this line:

```
win.fullscreen();
```

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#type-AppWindow

If you hit escape while your app is running you may get the title bar back, but next time it runs it will go fullscreen again.